# Instilled - is there a better word or phrase specifically for a child getting their interest/love of something from a parent

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for something to better evoke the gratitude one might feel towards their parent (or anyone, but parent in this case) for sharing their love of something (music, reading, etc.) in such a way that it became a cherished part of the child's own life. It would be used in something like an obituary where the wording we've got currently is "His family inherited his love of reading and music" and I'm suggesting something more like "He instilled his love..." - neither seem sufficient though.

Comment: "His family *inherited his love of* reading and music" read just right.

Comment: *Passed down* or *imparted •* can be used also.

Comment: You really do not want to say he instilled his love of reading in his family. Sounds awful.

Comment: 'He passed down his love ...' is perhaps not quite as personal as the original – the best, as @Yosef attests.

Comment: Yes, _instilled_ sounds as though he enforced it on them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hard to define "better word", I just feel like there's something that conveys more than "just" passing along

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far, sounds like the original is probably the best bet

Comment: He cultivated a love for reading and music in all whose lives he touched.

Comment: @KateBunting While it does sound like that, I'm pretty sure I've heard it used when the parent merely encouraged it actively. You can force someone to take an action, but it's hard to force them to like or love it.